# Eclipse Failing to Rebuild Project with Struts2

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, struts

I am new to struts, and I am having an issue when automatically rebuilding projects in Eclipse.

When using the Tomcat launcher, everything works fine with the jars in /WEB-INF/lib and my struts.xml in /WEB-INF/classes.

After I modify my source and the project goes to rebuild, Eclipse always throws errors saying that it cannot be restarted. Using Tomcat Launcher to restart the service works fine. I have tried moving the struts.xml file to /WEB-INF/src/, but it does not work either.

Here's the error message I get:

```
    Sep 26, 2012 9:11:56 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
    SEVERE: Exception starting filter struts2
    Unable to load configuration. - [unknown location]
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:450)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:74)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:51)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:295)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:422)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:115)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4072)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4726)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload(StandardContext.java:3461)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.backgroundProcess(WebappLoader.java:426)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1361)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1653)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1662)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1662)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1642)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: Unable to load configuration. - [unknown location]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:69)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:390)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:437)
        ... 15 more
    Caused by: Caught exception while loading file struts-default.xml - [unknown location]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadConfigurationFiles(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:958)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadDocuments(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:163)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.init(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:130)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:209)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:66)
        ... 17 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.xerces.parsers.XIncludeAwareParserConfiguration cannot be cast to org.apache.xerces.xni.parser.XMLParserConfiguration
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl.newDocumentBuilder(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.SAX2DOM.createDocument(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.SAX2DOM.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.runtime.output.TransletOutputHandlerFactory.getSerializationHandler(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.getOutputHandler(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerHandlerImpl.setResult(Unknown Source)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.DomHelper$DOMBuilder.setup(DomHelper.java:205)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.DomHelper$DOMBuilder.<init>(DomHelper.java:190)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.DomHelper$DOMBuilder.<init>(DomHelper.java:181)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.DomHelper$DOMBuilder.<init>(DomHelper.java:167)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.DomHelper.parse(DomHelper.java:107)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadConfigurationFiles(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:949)
        ... 21 more
    Sep 26, 2012 9:11:56 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
    SEVERE: Error filterStart
    Sep 26, 2012 9:11:56 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
```

Comment: problem might be in jar's comparability. Just update your query with the JAR's what you are using.